# Convert a txt file to dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

How do I convert a .txt file with the following form of data to a pandas dataframe?

For example, this is the txt file with the structure `(x1, y1, z1), (x2, y2, z2), ... (xn, yn, zn),`

`(108.222994365147, 16.077177357808345, 17.5), (108.22299074891866, 16.07718225312858, 17.5), (108.2229869226013, 16.077186986051835, 17.5), (108.22298289347849, 16.077191547568788, 17.5),`

And after converting I want it to be like this

```
                    x                     y       z
1    108.222994365147    16.077177357808345    17.5   
2  108.22299074891866     16.07718225312858    17.5
3   108.2229869226013    16.077186986051835    17.5
4  108.22298289347849    16.077191547568788    17.5
```

Comment: You probably should write some code. [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach would solve your problem

```
import pandas as pd
import re

with open({YOUR_FILE_LOCATION}, "r") as f:
    s = f.read()

pattern = re.compile("\(([\d\.]+),[ ]*([\d\.]+),[ ]*([\d+\.]+)\)")
pd.DataFrame(pattern.findall(s), columns=["x","y","z"]).astype(float)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
            x          y     z
0  108.222994  16.077177  17.5
1  108.222991  16.077182  17.5
2  108.222987  16.077187  17.5
3  108.222983  16.077192  17.5
```

Once the file is imported, all the patterns of interest (3 comma separated floats between brackets) are matched and passed to a `DataFrame` constructor as a list of lists. Then everything is cast to `float`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try. But what is ``read``?

Comment: @TúMaiXuân I corrected a typo in the code - `f.read()` instead of `read(f)`. With `read` you import the content of your file, in this case, that would be your data.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution using [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) and [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

with open({YOUR_FILE_LOCATION}, "r") as file:
    data = file.read()

data = data.replace('(', '').replace('),', '\n')[:-1]
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), header=None)
df.columns = ["x", "y", "z"]
```

**Output:**

```
    x           y           z
0   108.222994  16.077177   17.5
1   108.222991  16.077182   17.5
2   108.222987  16.077187   17.5
3   108.222983  16.077192   17.5
```

Answer (score 0):

data = pd.read_csv('file1.txt', sep=" ", header=None)

data.columns = ["x", "y", "z"]

try this

Comment: I don't think this will work. There are no newlines between each row of data, so this solution will put all the data in one row.